# What are the differences between HasOne and References in nhibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

What are the differences between `HasOne()` and `References()` in nhibernate?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`HasOne` creates a one-to-one mapping between tables for you. `References` creates a typical relational many-to-one relationship.

More defined:

- a one-to-one relationship means that when one record exists in one table, it must (or can) have one and at most one record in the other referenced table. *Example:* User table and Options table (one user has one fixed set of options)
- a many-to-one relationship means that when one records exists in one table, it can have many related records in another table. *Example:* User table and Purchase table (one user can do many purchases).

*Note:* where I say *table* you can replace that safely with *class* or *entity* as you wish, when using FluentNH it's easy to use them interchangeably.

This is more precisely explained in [this fluentnhibernate wiki article](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping).